# Why do none of the procedures for EFSA use the SVL VOR-DME?

Tags: approach, aeronautical-charts, navaids

This is inspired by [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/92125/8730). Looking at all the approach and STAR charts for EFSA in Savonlinna, Finland, they are all RNAV. The Linna VOR-DME is not used for any of them even though it is located a half mile off the arrival end of runway 12. Why is this navaid not used for any of the procedures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Finnish AIP](https://www.ais.fi/ais/aip/ge/EF_ENR_4_1_EN.pdf), LINNA (SVL) is only a DME, not a VOR/DME.

Comment: I think it used to be a VOR/DME, but the VOR was probably discontinued for economic reasons.

Comment: Yep, that is the general plan for many VOR/DME in Europe, I think. Presumably it would be a good idea to revert that trend now, at least in areas affected by Russian intentional or "collateral" GPS jamming.

Comment: @tml Most (all?) airliners can still do RNAV from DME/DME/IRU in the event of a GPS outage. No VORs needed.

Comment: @StephenS Would the DME distances need to be listed on the charts?

Comment: @TomMcW Nope. The FMS already knows where all the DMEs are, so it can triangulate its own lat/long. It’s not as accurate as GNSS, of course, but RNAV/RNP was designed with different levels specifically to account for that.

Comment: @StephenS Sure, DME/DME is enough for enroute RNAV, but the approaches at EFSA are RNP or ILS with GNSS required, so not enough. When SVL was still a VOR/DME, they probably had a VOR approach or a VOR-based procedure turn onto the ILS.

Comment: @Bianfable I don’t see any good reason to require GNSS on that ILS, and you wouldn’t even need RNAV at all if there were a teardrop or PT off the VOR as is common in many other countries. Perhaps Finland just doesn’t want you flying there if you don’t have all the latest toys.

Answer (score 1):

The VOR was discontinued a few years back, they've been disabling VORs one by one here in Finland. It's only a DME now. (I know, I've flown a Cessna to Savonlinna a few times.)